# how to mount [bind] an external hard drive folder using UUID to another folder on a pc

Tags: mount, path, bind, uuid

### **in short:**

on pc:

```
/home/user/Music:
├─music_from_disk_1
└─music_from_disk_2
```

on 2 HDD's in root: /music, /docs, /photos.

need to automatically mount `HDD1/music` to `.../music_from_disk_1` and `HDD2/music` to `.../music_from_disk_2` regardless of the number of previously mounted file systems from other devices and from the sequence of connecting the hard disk drives.

### **detailed:**

i have 2 HDD. UUID HDD1 is `4E1AE` and UUID2 is `A7B1A`. there are `/music`, `/docs`, `/photos` folders exists in root on each HDD.

in pc/music i have 2 folders. one for each `HDD/music` folder :

```
/home/user/Music:
├─music_from_disk_1
└─music_from_disk_2
```

and the same hierarchy for photos.

I need to set everything up so that when the HDD1 is connected, the `/music` folder from HDD1 is automatically mounted into `/home/user/Music/music_from_disk_1`. and then i plug in HDD2. `/music` from HDD2 mounted into  `/home/user/Music/music_from_disk_2`. and for /docs, /photos folders the same way.

and no matter what the sequence of connecting the disks and how many other disks and devices I have already mounted.

using UUIDs just to avoid confusion. if there are other more convenient options, of course I will use them.

it doesn't work for me. maybe I'm misusing it or don't know the additional options:

> i know how to mount folder to folder. `sudo mount --bind /from /to`
> and in `/etc/fstab` wrote `/from /to none bind 0 0`. so that after
> rebooting everything is mounted again.
>
> ```
> it works only when you know where HDD[1|2] is mounted now.
> ```

> and also know how to mount HDD partition to some folder using UUID:
> `/dev/disk/by-uuid/4E1AE /home/user/Music/ auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0` Gnome Disk Utility wrote it in
> /etc/fstab. "Edit Mount Options"->"Automatic Mount Options".
>
> ```
> partition to folder but not folder to folder.
> ```

if there is no simple solution, can i probably use the bash(or other) script to check the UUID and mount it in the appropriate folders? I don't know how to write it and don't know how to automatically launch script when any device is connected.

I also know that there is a way to combine 2 partitions into one when mounting without using raid, but I don't need it.

i have Ubuntu 20.04 installed.

Comment: Do those drives already automatically mount under `/media/username/`?

Comment: yes, both of them

Answer (score 0):

You could create a symlink between the folders and the mount points:

```
$ ln -s /media/user/4E1AE/music /home/user/Music/music_from_disk_1
$ ln -s /media/user/A7B1A/music /home/user/Music/music_from_disk_2
```

Comment: `ln -s /media/user/8A94F/music /home/user/music/music_from_disk_1`
when is mounted trying to open it and get an error:
the link "music" is broken
this link cannot be used because its target /media/user/4E1AE/music doesn't exist

Comment: You should adapt the answer to your current setup. It was not a completely generic answer and `8A94F` is not mentioned in your question. You could treat it as `music_from_disk_3`. Try to understand what the symbolic link does so that you can adapt and extend the commands. If in doubt, remove and recreate them, you can see them as just pointers.